# UWP side loaded xbox app cant access localhost

Tags: uwp, xbox

I have created a Xbox app using UWP and side loaded it to Xbox but I cant access the local host but can access the server though. I checked and found a solution like disable network  isolation but that's for app side loaded in PC. How can I do that in Xbox.please help

Comment: how do yo try to exempt your localhost? can you say more details about it...

Comment: I haven't tried to exempt it. I am trying to access it through local server hosted in local iis

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the **Private Network Client/Server** capability in the `Package.appxmanifest` file by opening it, switching to the **Capabilities** tab and ticking the box next to this capability. This enables localhost network communication.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your Xbox through PowerShell via IP with this command:

1. net start WinRM
2. Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value *"machine-name or IP Address"*
3. Enter-PSSession -ComputerName *"machine-name or IP Address"* -Credential *"machine-name or IP Address or localhost"*\Administrator
4. checknetisolation loopbackexempt -a -n=*"Your App Package Family Name"*

for getting *App Package Family Name* go to **Package.appxmanifes** file > **Packaging** tab > **Package Family Name**

Comment: Where should I do this? In Xbox or in my machine?and the IP address is of Xbox?

Comment: From your windows which connect to your Xbox through wireless or cable network.
Yes you must enter your Xbox IP Address